# XML link into a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm having trouble getting this page (http://ventrilostatus.net/xml/V98.DARKSTARLLC.COM:3789/) to array into php. I'm not very good with xml and I currently can only get it to display:
Server
Channel
Channel
Channel
(etc)

Could anyone help me get it to show the channel name and the users?
if there are not clients when you look at it it will be:

```
<client admin="1" cid="994" phan="0" ping="186" sec="56935" name="WHERE USER'S NAME HIS HERE" comm=""/>
```

Comment: You can use a XML-PHP library which converts valid XML code to a php object or array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry this is the code I updated:

```
<?PHP
echo "<table width=\"209\" bgcolor=\"#0d0d0d\">";
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://ventrilostatus.net/xml/V98.DARKSTARLLC.COM:3789/'); // for files
//$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlContent); // for strings

foreach($xml->channel as $lobby) {
echo "<tr><td>";
echo "<img src='http://view.light-speed.com//images/s_vent2/server_icon.gif' />";
echo "<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">";
echo $lobby->attributes()->name;
echo "</font>";
echo "</td></tr>";
}

foreach($xml->channel->channel as $channel) {
if($channel->attributes()->prot == "0"){
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo "<img src='http://view.light-speed.com//images/s_vent2/channel_0_empty.gif' />";
echo "<font color=\"#ffffff\">";
echo $channel->attributes()->name;
echo "</font>";
echo "</td></tr>";    
                                        }else{
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;";                                            
echo "<img src='http://view.light-speed.com//images/s_vent2/channel_1_empty.gif' />";
echo "<font color=\"#ffffff\">";
echo $channel->attributes()->name;
echo "</font>";
echo "</td></tr>";                                          
  }

if($channel->client){
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($channel->client); $i++ ){
$client = $channel->client[ $i ];

        if ( $client->attributes()->cid != $client->attributes()->cid )

            continue;
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo "<img src='http://view.light-speed.com//images/s_vent2/player.gif' /><font color=\"#009e1a\">";
if($client->attributes()->admin == "1"){ 

     echo $client->attributes()->name; 
     echo "&nbsp;<font color=\"#ff0000\">(Admin)</font>";
     }else{
     echo $client->attributes()->name;
     }

echo "</td></tr>";
}
}

foreach($channel->channel as $subchannel) {
if($subchannel->attributes()->prot == "0"){
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo "<img src='http://view.light-speed.com//images/s_vent2/channel_0_empty.gif' />";
echo "<font color=\"#ffffff\">";
echo $subchannel->attributes()->name;
echo "</font>";
echo "</td></tr>";    
                                        }else{
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";                                            
echo "<img src='http://view.light-speed.com//images/s_vent2/channel_1_empty.gif' />";
echo "<font color=\"#ffffff\">";
echo $subchannel->attributes()->name;
echo "</font>";
echo "</td></tr>";                                          
  }

if($subchannel->client){
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($subchannel->client); $i++ ){
$client = $subchannel->client[ $i ];

        if ( $client->attributes()->cid != $client->attributes()->cid )

            continue;
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo "<img src='http://view.light-speed.com//images/s_vent2/player.gif' /><font color=\"#009e1a\">";
if($client->attributes()->admin == "1"){ 

     echo $client->attributes()->name; 
     echo "&nbsp;<font color=\"#ff0000\">(Admin)</font>";
     }else{
     echo $client->attributes()->name;
     }

echo "</td></tr>";
}
}

foreach($subchannel->channel as $subchannel2) {
if($subchannel2->attributes()->prot == "0"){
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo "<img src='http://view.light-speed.com//images/s_vent2/channel_0_empty.gif' />";
echo "<font color=\"#ffffff\">";
echo $subchannel2->attributes()->name;
echo "</font>";
echo "</td></tr>";    
                                        }else{
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";                                            
echo "<img src='http://view.light-speed.com//images/s_vent2/channel_1_empty.gif' />";
echo "<font color=\"#ffffff\">";
echo $subchannel2->attributes()->name;
echo "</font>";
echo "</td></tr>";                                          
  }

if($subchannel2->client){
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($subchannel2->client); $i++ ){
$client = $subchannel2->client[ $i ];

        if ( $client->attributes()->cid != $client->attributes()->cid )

            continue;
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo "<img src='http://view.light-speed.com//images/s_vent2/player.gif' /><font color=\"#009e1a\">";
if($client->attributes()->admin == "1"){ 

     echo $client->attributes()->name; 
     echo "&nbsp;<font color=\"#ff0000\">(Admin)</font>";
     }else{
     echo $client->attributes()->name;
     }

echo "</td></tr>";
}
}

foreach($subchannel2->channel as $subchannel3) {
if($subchannel3->attributes()->prot == "0"){
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo "<img src='http://view.light-speed.com//images/s_vent2/channel_0_empty.gif' />";
echo "<font color=\"#ffffff\">";
echo $subchannel3->attributes()->name;
echo "</font>";
echo "</td></tr>";    
                                        }else{
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";                                            
echo "<img src='http://view.light-speed.com//images/s_vent2/channel_1_empty.gif' />";
echo "<font color=\"#ffffff\">";
echo $subchannel3->attributes()->name;
echo "</font>";
echo "</td></tr>";                                          
  }

if($subchannel3->client){
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($subchannel3->client); $i++ ){
$client = $subchannel3->client[ $i ];

        if ( $client->attributes()->cid != $client->attributes()->cid )

            continue;
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo "<img src='http://view.light-speed.com//images/s_vent2/player.gif' /><font color=\"#009e1a\">";
if($client->attributes()->admin == "1"){ 

     echo $client->attributes()->name; 
     echo "&nbsp;<font color=\"#ff0000\">(Admin)</font>";
     }else{
     echo $client->attributes()->name;
     }

echo "</td></tr>";
}
}
}

}
}
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

which shows

- lobby
- channel
- subchannel
- subchannel

Answer (score 0):

U can use the simple_xml functions of PHP to load the xml file into a class.

http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php

Edit with an example:

```
// XML example
$xmlContent = '<server name="GuiltyofDestruction" phonetic="God" comment="http://guiltyofdestruction.com" auth="1" maxclients="25" uptime="137600" platform="Linux-i386" version="3.0.6" channelcount="36" clientcount="1" voicecodec="GSM 6.10" voiceformat="44 KHz, 16 bit"><channel cid="0" pid="-1" prot="0" name="Lobby" comm="">
    <channel cid="1033" pid="0" prot="1" name="Admin" comm=""/>
        <channel cid="1030" pid="0" prot="0" name="AFK Channel" comm="AFK">
            <client admin="1" cid="1030" phan="0" ping="182" sec="67575" name="US_ChairForce" comm=""/>
        </channel>
    </channel>
</server>';

// Loading XML information as object

//$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://ventrilostatus.net/xml/V98.DARKSTARLLC.COM:3789/'); // for files
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlContent); // for strings
foreach($xml->channel->channel as $channel) {
    if($channel->client)
        echo $channel->client->attributes()->name; // returns "US_ChairForce"
}
```

I think it's clear now. You have to iterate through every channel and look for clients.

Comment: like I said I'm not good with xml, I have actually tried reading this before. My problem is I can only get it to post Server - channel - channel - channel - etc. Because the xml isnt <server>SERVER NAME</server><channel>CHANNEL NAME</channel> I cant figure out how to get the information.

Comment: You can iterate through every child object and you can access all attributes of the tag with $obj->attributes()->attribute. If you want to have the users, iterate through every object with a foreach loop.

Comment: don't forget to tick this. ;)